# Removing strings in brackets for unicode lines - python

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary, brackets

i've got some problems with my regex and removing my the strongs bounded by brackets.

here's my code:

```
import sys, re
import codecs

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

reader = codecs.open("input",'r','utf-8')
p = re.compile('s/[\[\(].+?[\]\)]//g', re.DOTALL)
# i've also tried several regex but it didn't work
# p = re.compile('\{\{*?.*?\}\}', re.DOTALL)
# p = re.compile('\{\{*.*?\}\}', re.DOTALL)

for row in reader:
    if ("(" in row) and (")" not in row):
        continue
    if row.count("(") != row.count(")"):
        continue
    else:
        row2 = p.sub('', row)
        print row2
```

for the input textfiles it looks something like this:

```
가시 돋친(신랄한)평 spinosity
가장 완전한 (같은 종류의 것 중에서)   unabridged
(알코올이)표준강도(50%) 이하의 underproof
(암초 awash
치명적인(fatal) capital
열을) 전도하다    transmit
```

the required output should look like this:

```
가시 돋친평  spinosity
가장 완전한  unabridged
표준강도 이하의    underproof
치명적인    capital
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144326/regex-to-remove-all-punctuation-and-anything-enclosed-by-brackets managed to do it somehow. can someone help with the re regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, re
import codecs

#reload(sys)
#sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

#prepareing the examples to work on
writer = codecs.open("input.txt",'w','utf-8')
examples = [u'가시 돋친(신랄한)평 spinosity',
            u'가장 완전한 (같은 종류의 것 중에서)',
            u'알코올이)표준강도(50%) 이하의 underproof',
            u'(암초 awash',
            u'치명적인(fatal) capital']
for exampl in examples:
    writer.write(exampl+"\n")
writer.write(exampl)
writer.close()

reader = codecs.open("input.txt",'r','utf-8')

#order of patterns is important,
#if you remove brackets first, the other won't find anything
patterns_to_remove = [r"\(.{1,}\)",r"[\(\)]"]

#one pattern would work just fine, with the loop is a bit more clear
#pat = r"(\(.{1,}\))|([\(\)])"    
#for row in reader:
#    row = re.sub(pat,'',row)#,re.U)
#    print row

reader.seek(0)
for row in reader:
    for pat in patterns_to_remove:
        row = re.sub(pat,'',row)#,re.U)
    print row
reader.close()
```

Comment: nice regex, it works. so just some clarification, "re.U" means re in unicode right? why is it r"[\(\)]", why wont r"\(\)" do? can you explain a little on .{1,} , i'm not very good with regex. Thanks a lot, the code works. normally, i'll skip the seek(0) and close() though.

Comment: To be honest, I think re.U is not needed at all, it might be a leftover from my playing with it - I'll comment it out. r"[\(\)]" is to remove all brackets, so it would transform "some(thing)else" or "something)else"  to "somethingelse" while r"\(\)" would look purely for "()" so "something()else" to "somethingelse". According to the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), [] is used to indicate a set of characters.